# Getting Product category in Amazon

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’ve tried using IMPORTXML on Google sheets to get Amazon product category but it’s always returning N/A.

Is there a way for me to get it?

Here’s the Amazon link https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07H8Q5S1T

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=importxml(url,"//div[@id='nav-subnav']/@data-category")
```

or

```
=index(importxml(url,"//div[@id='nav-subnav']"),1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works and I learnt something new! also, is it possible for me to get this specific data? <span class="nav-a-content"> Garden &amp; Outdoors </span>  specifically "Garden & Outdoors"

Comment: try `=index(importxml(url,"//div[@id='nav-subnav']"),1)`

Comment: do you need any other help?